# How to identify ThisWorkbook module using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Using Excel 2010.

I need to add code to a remote Excel file where ThisWorkbook module has been renamed, let's say to "DashboardWorkbook". I don't know however the new name, can be anything but *I need to identify this module programmatically* in order to add more code to Sub Workbook_Open().

I am opening this remote file, then I go through all it's components:

```
Private Sub AddProcedureToWorkbook(wb As Workbook)
  Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
  Dim oComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
  Dim oCodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule

  Set VBProj = wb.VBProject 
  For Each oComp In VBProj.VBComponents
    If *[check here if oComp was formerly ThisWorkbook but now renamed]* Then
      Set oCodeMod = oComp.CodeModule
        'add new code here
      ...etc, etc
    End If
  Next

End Sub
```

In Excel interface, ThisWorkbook has a different icon so it seems to be a different module type but I could not figure out what specific property to read in order to identify it?

To complicate things even more, sometimes Sub Workbook_Open() doesn't exist, therefore I need to add it at the right place...

Thank you,

M.R.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sheets and books can be accessed directly from code by their `CodeName` (different from display name aka just `Name`).
This is also their VBComponent name.

```
Private Sub AddProcedureToWorkbook(wb As Workbook)
  Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
  Dim oComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
  Dim oCodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule

  Set VBProj = wb.VBProject
  Set oComp = VBProj.VBComponents(wb.CodeName)
  Set oCodeMod = oComp.CodeModule

  oCodeMod.AddFromString "sub Hi()" & vbNewLine & "msgbox ""Hi.""" & vbNewLine & "end sub"
End Sub
```

Comment: Much better than a search!

Answer (score 2):

Each of the `VBProj.VBComponents` items has a `Properties` collection.  The set of properties of the Workbook object is different to the others (Sheets, Modules etc).

Pick a unique property of the Workbook and search the components collection for that.

Try this

```
Private Function FindThisWorkbook(wb As Workbook) As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim oComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim oP As Property

    Set VBProj = wb.VBProject
    For Each oComp In VBProj.VBComponents
        Set oP = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set oP = oComp.Properties("ActiveSheet")
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not oP Is Nothing Then
            ' Found it
            Set FindThisWorkbook = oComp
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, this is an alternate way of identifying ThisWorkbook, I could browse through all properties names in a loop ( oComp.Properties(i).Name) and find for example if "ActiveSheet" as you suggested or maybe "Worksheets" is one of them. This will uniquely identify ThisWorkbook module.