# Is a Friend Property Get in ThisworkBook possible in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, model-view-controller, userform

I try to replicate the second answer [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47357708/vba-destroy-a-modeless-userform-instance-properly). Here is my code for ThisWorkBook:

## Code

```
Option Explicit

Private Type TView
    UserInterFace As UIFrm
    Model as UIModel
End Type

Private this As TView

Friend Property Get UserInterFace() As UIFrm
    If this.UserInterFace Is Nothing Then
        Set this.UserInterFace = New UIFrm
    End If

    Set UserInterFace = this.UserInterFace
End Property

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not this.UserInterFace Is Nothing Then
        Unload this.UserInterFace
        Set this.UserInterFace = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

This should - according to the answer in the link above - make me able to do this in another module of the same project:

```
ThisWorkbook.UserInterface.Show
```

## Context

I want to make a modeless Userform where the instance "lives" as long as the Workbook. I have heard that this could cause issues but nothing specific. I want to do this in order to preserve my UIModel.

`UIModel` is the Model Class `UIFrm` the Modeless UI Userform

## Problem

I am not able to access the costum property using `ThisWorkBook.UserInterFace` and if I declare the `Property Get` as Public I will get a compilation error about: Private Properties not beeing able to be accessed publically.

**Is this even possible to have a Property Get inside the `ThisWorkbook`-Object ?**

Comment: I tried with a simplified case (`Private m_Test As Double` 
`Friend Property Get Test() As Double: Test = m_Test: End Property`) in ThisWorkbook and got no problem accessing `ThisWorkbook.Test`.

Comment: @VincentG I am using excel 2010. Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: @GSerg That was the issue! I am using the german version where the object is translated into german. The Translated object is the one with `Test` in it. You can put this as an answer.

Comment: @GSerg I used to be wondering why `ThisWorkbook` appears twice in Intellisence, not anymore, thanks to you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ThisWorkbook` may not be what you think it is.

There is `Application.ThisWorkbook`, which is a property of the `Application` object. It returns the workbook in which the code that calls this property resides.

There is also "just" `ThisWorkbook`, a [code name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33486349/11683) that represents the Workbook class instance in which your code resides. The problem is that this `ThisWorkbook`, unlike the `Application.ThisWorkbook`, is subject to localization. It is not a part of an object model, it is an arbitrary name.

For the English version of Excel, the localized name happens to be `ThisWorkbook` too.
For non-English Excels, it's going to be something different.

Thus, due to scope precedence, `ThisWorkbook` resolves to "the code name" in the English Excel and to `Application.ThisWorkbook` in non-English Excels.

They are the same object, but the Friend properties are only accessible "truly internally", so when accessing the workbook via the `Application.ThisWorkbook` route, you cannot see them.

The fix is to rename the localized `ThisWorkbook` object back to `ThisWorkbook` in the project tree. Like sheet code names, this change is local to the file.

Using the localized name instead of `ThisWorkbook` in your code will also work.