# How to change the 'Sheet1' name to a custom spreadsheet name like "AAA BBB"?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm very new to vba that's why I rely so much on internet search. What I'm trying to do now is I want to make an Advanced Filter using a ComboBox where a user will type a keyword and it will be automatically be displayed on the ListBox (Extracting data as the user type).

Since I don't don't know to do it, I searched for tutorials online and I found this code from https://www.razakmcr.in/2017/10/ms-excell-listbox-search-by-textbox-vba.html. <- that's what I'm trying to do exactly. But I noticed that his sheet is named to default 'Sheet1'. I have a sheet named "DATA STOCK" and I've tried to change Sheet1 to "DATA STOCK" but I got an error. I want to try his code because it may be a huge help.

Here is his code:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

Me.TextBox1.Text = StrConv(Me.TextBox1.Text, vbProperCase)
Dim i As Long
Me.ListBox1.Clear
On Error Resume Next

For i = 1 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet1.Range("A:A"))
    a = Len(Me.TextBox1.Text)
    If Left(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Text, a) = Left(Me.TextBox1.Text, a) Then
        Me.ListBox1.AddItem Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value
        Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

What I did is for example: `For i = 1 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet1.Range("A:A"))` to `For i = 1 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(("DATA STOCK").Range("A:A"))`

Anyway, here is my code for the WHOLE ComboBox that serves as an Advanced Filter:

```
Private Sub cmbSearch_Change()

    Me.cmbSearch.Text = StrConv(Me.cmbSearch.Text, vbProperCase)
    Dim i As Long
    Me.listHeader.Clear
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 1 To x
    a = Len(Me.cmbSearch.Text)
    If Left("DATA STOCK").Cells(i, 1).Text, a) = Left(Me.cmbSearch.Text, a) Then
    Me.cmbSearch.AddItem Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value
    Me.cmbSearch.List(listHeader.ListCount - 1, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value
    End If
    Next i

    'THE FF CODE WILL DISPLAY THE VALUE ON THE LISTBOX FROM THE COMBOBOX SELECTION
    x = Sheets("DATA STOCK").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For y = 2 To x
            If Sheets("DATA STOCK").Cells(y, 1).Text = cmbSearch.Value Then
                cmbSchema.Text = Sheets("DATA STOCK").Cells(y, 1)
                cmbEnvironment.Text = Sheets("DATA STOCK").Cells(y, 2)
                cmbHost.Text = Sheets("DATA STOCK").Cells(y, 3)
                cmbIP.Text = Sheets("DATA STOCK").Cells(y, 4)
                cmbAccessible.Text = Sheets("DATA STOCK").Cells(y, 5)
                cmbLast.Text = Sheets("DATA STOCK").Cells(y, 6)
                cmbConfirmation.Text = Sheets("DATA STOCK").Cells(y, 7)
                cmbProjects.Text = Sheets("DATA STOCK").Cells(y, 8)

                UserForm1.listHeader.RowSource = "A" + CStr(y) + ": H" + CStr(y)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next y

End Sub
```

Can you help me how to create an Advanced Filter?

Answer (score 0):

`Sheet1` in this example is the [code name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33486349/11683) of the sheet.

Your DATA STOCK sheet also has a code name, and most likely it's not DATA STOCK. Look it up in the project tree and use instead of `Sheet1`.

[image]

Alternatively, use `Worksheets("DATA STOCK")` in place of `Sheet1`, but then your code will rely on users not renaming the sheet.

Comment: i'm sorry can you please explain it further? Something like a 14 year old without knowledge in coding would understand. I'm really having a hard time

Comment: @stella Are you having a hard time looking up the code name or replacing occurrences of `Sheet1` from the example with `Worksheets("DATA STOCK")`?

Comment: yeah actually having a hard time with creating an advanced search haha. But since I found an example I'd like to try it. And yes, I don't know how to change `Sheet1` to `Worksheets("DATA STOCK")`

Comment: @stella You've managed to change `Sheet1.Range("A:A")` to `("DATA STOCK").Range("A:A")`, so you should be able to change it to `Worksheets("DATA STOCK").Range("A:A")` too?

Comment: Example: `Sheet1.Cells` to `Worksheets("DATA STOCK").Cells` ?? Is this how it should look like? I wanna change `Sheet1` to my spreadsheet name Data Stock