# Error '424' on calling other worksheet's sub

Tags: excel, vba

I've looked on some similar question of "Object required on calling sub", but None of them seems to help with my problem. I want to call a sub(for example, in sheet2) from a sub in sheet1 like

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear
Call sheet2.generate  <== where the error comes from
End Sub
```

where generate is the sub name on sheet2 which don't require any parameter
but it tells me that Object required and sendback an error.
I've tried:

without using call

```vb
sheet2.generate
```

without sheet name

```
generate
```

```
call generate
```

and adding a useless parameter for calling( also added to generate sub)

```
call sheet2.generate(1)
```

but it's not working too, so i detele that parameter as it have no use in the code.

there is no problem on generate sub(which i test for many time)

still, all of the above do not work for me, can someone provide a *vaild* way to solve this?

Comment: Do you in fact have a sheet with a [code name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54501849/11683) of `sheet2`?

Comment: i am using chinese version of excal tho... so the codename is in chinese, and i am calling it using the normal name

Comment: No, you are calling it using the code name. If `sheet2` was the normal name, you would have used `Worksheets("sheet2").generate`.

Comment: @GSerg, so i should call it with code name?

Comment: @WhereisourMonica You can use either. But you cannot use the normal name as a code name or vice versa. Unless, of course, you make them the same.

Comment: no,i just use "sheet2" as example, the real name i replace with is called "hiddenreveal".

Comment: maybe the problem is at the generate sub? Cause it seems like I ```Dim``` a Int inside the sub. Which maybe make the problem?

Comment: VBA doesn't get to the `Generate` sub, it stops at the dot in `Sheet2.` and says "wait a minute, that's not an object!" - make sure your module says `Option Explicit` at the top. Then try `Application.Run "'name of the sheet'!Generate"`

Comment: Consider adding a standard module to your VBA project, and moving the `Generate` procedure there; then, just `[Call] Generate` will be enough to invoke it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the problem is not at calling function,but instead, stuffs ***INSIDE*** function have problem, and debug arrow goes *function* and says "error 1004", after fixing some variable problem of the function, the problem no longer shows.

## *BRUH*