# "Subscript Out Of Range"

Tags: excel, vba

I want to Search Data in my Excel Workbook

This code:

```vb
Private Sub search_Click()
    Dim totRows As Long, i As Long

    totRows = Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    If kodebus.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox "Enter the code you wish to search!"
    End If

    For i = 2 To totRows
        If Trim(Sheet4.Cells(i, 1)) <> Trim(kodebus.Text) And i = totRows Then
            MsgBox "Code not found!"
        End If
        If Trim(Sheet4.Cells(i, 1)) = Trim(kodebus.Text) Then
            kodebus.Text = Sheet4.Cells(i, 1)
            namabus.Text = Sheet4.Cells(i, 2)
            jurusanbus.Text = Sheet4.Cells(i, 3)
            hargabus.Text = Sheet4.Cells(i, 4)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Finally I get an Error, this message is "Subscript Out Of Range".
And get the position an Error in the code:

```vb
totRows = Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
```

Please help ve to solve it, thanks

Comment: So you do not have a sheet named `Sheet4`. You (probably) do have sheet with a [`CodeName`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33486349/11683) of `Sheet4`, but you do not have a sheet with a `Name` of `"Sheet4"`.

Comment: Use `Sheet4.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count`

Comment: or you have multiple workbooks open and the wrong workbook is active. If you are sure that your workbook has `sheet4` and the code is in that workbook then try this `totRows = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count` or fully qualify it with the relevant workbook. One more possibilitiy is (i.e if you can see "Sheet") is that the worksheet name has leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: Thank you All, for answer my question... solved it,